# How to store the uploaded value into redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi i am working on upload file by using react and redux and ant design for the designing page. I am able to successfully send the selected file to the backend and also able to store into database.Now in response i return some file metadata which i need to store in the redux store.

Now the problem is when i go to the next page and come back on the previous page i am calling the redux to store the complete form field into redux store.
so now for my upload filed it get updated with some object which content file and filelist, instead i want to save response metadata which i am returning from backend.

I have tried to assignee my upload field with the response metadata but when i go back and forth it get override with some object which content file and filelist.
So i am not able to figure it out what wrong i am doing. Can any one help me on  these

**A.js file:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import uploadFile from './B'
import { Button, Form, Icon, Upload } from "antd";


export class A extends Component {
    uploadFileHandler = ({ file, onSuccess }) => {
        uploadFile(file, onSuccess).then(data => {
            this.props.updateProjectReport({
                projectReport: data
            });
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <Form.Item>
                <br />
                {getFieldDecorator("projectReport", {
                    initialValue: this.props.project.projectReport
                })(
                    <Upload name="file" customRequest={this.uploadFileHandler}>
                        <Button>
                            <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
                        </Button>
                    </Upload>
                )}
            </Form.Item>
        )
    }
}

export default A
```

**B.js file:**

```js
import axios from "axios";

const uploadFile = (props, onSuccess) => {
    let fileDetails;
    console.log("upload file call");
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("fileName", props);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type":
          "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryqTqJIxvkWFYqvP5s"
      }
    };
    return axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/upload", data, config)
      .then(resp => {
        if (resp.status === 200) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            onSuccess("ok");
          }, 0);
          fileDetails = resp.data;
          console.log(fileDetails);
              return fileDetails;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

export default uploadFile;
```

This is the data get save when i go back and forth in the reducer.

```
projectReport: {
        file: {
          uid: 'rc-upload-1567617261814-3',
          lastModified: 1565243029823,
          lastModifiedDate: '2019-08-08T05:43:49.823Z',
          name: 'rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg',
          size: 20775,
          type: 'image/jpeg',
          percent: 0,
          originFileObj: {
            uid: 'rc-upload-1567617261814-3'
          },
          status: 'done',
          response: 'ok'
        },
        fileList: [
          {
            uid: 'rc-upload-1567617261814-3',
            lastModified: 1565243029823,
            lastModifiedDate: '2019-08-08T05:43:49.823Z',
            name: 'rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg',
            size: 20775,
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            percent: 0,
            originFileObj: {
              uid: 'rc-upload-1567617261814-3'
            },
            status: 'done',
            response: 'ok'
          }
        ]
      }
```

Expected Json to be Store :

```
projectReport: {
        fileName: "rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg", 
        fileDownLoadUri: "http://localhost:8080/downloadFile/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg", 
        fileContentType: "image/jpeg", 
        fileSize: 20775
      }
```

Comment: First off, it looks like you have all the data you need to get the JSON you are looking for. You need to create a redux action and reducer for this state, and then dispatch the response (fileDetails) to that reducer. You might need to look into redux-thunk in order to create asynchronous dispatches (allows you to chain multiple dispatches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `uploadFileHandler` method should be call an action which would in turn call the `uploadFile` method in B.js and `dispatch` the result `fileDetails` to the reducer. In the reducer, you can create a new `projectReport` object from the `fileDetails` which would contain the necessary fields.

```
projectReport: {
    fileName: fileDetails.file.name, 
    fileDownLoadUri: SERVER_PATH +fileDetails.file.name", 
    fileContentType: fileDetails.file.type, 
    fileSize: fileDetails.file.size
  }
```

Comment: hey i am able to store data into the redux store but when i go back and forth the initialValue of  getFieldDecoratior is not getting update. So there any default filed which i can set it before uploding and then after uploding that default field get updated with my projectReport object.